# Declaring buttons in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jbutton

What is the best way to declare buttons in Android Studio java class? For example I have buttons & text fields:

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);
TextView A = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerA);
TextView B = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerB);
TextView C = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerC);
TextView D = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerD);
Button next_test = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next_Text);
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Android Studio throws errors when I declare them just below the class like so:

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);
TextView A = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerA);
TextView B = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerB);
TextView C = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerC);
TextView D = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerD);
Button next_test = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next_Text);
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {..........
```

It doesn't throw errors when I declare them in the methods they are need in, but then I have to declare them multiple times and also declare final in the oncreate.

Is there any way of declaring them just once?

Comment: You should `declare` them as class variables, and `assign` in your onCreate, after setting contentView.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must declare your views in `onCreate` . Put your `findViewById` methods in `onCreate`.

Comment: If you declare in onCreate, then they won't be accessible outside onCreate. Perhaps you meant assign, instead of declare?

Comment: i think question is not clear. I didnt see this quote "I want to use my fields globally " or etc. You know what i mean

Comment: Question is quite clear: `It doesn't throw errors when I declare them in the methods they are need in, but then I have to declare them multiple times and also declare final in the oncreate.`

Answer (score 3):

Your member variables should be accessible globally inside your class. but you can't find a view by id if the xml hasnt been inflated. this is how your code should look like:

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView t;
TextView A; 
TextView B;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); // THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT

t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);
A = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerA);
B = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerB);
....
}
```

The method `findViewById` looks for your views inside R.layout.your_layout... if you dont call `setContentView()`, it wont find anything and return null instead. Hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

proper way to declare views:

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv;

@Override
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.yout layout name);
 tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);
}
```

this is applicable for all view like button,imageview,linearlayout, imageview etc....

Answer (score 1):

You can do someting like this

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

   private TextView t;
   private TextView A;
   private TextView B;
   private TextView C;
   private TextView D;
   private Button next_test;
   private Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initialize();
   }

   private void initialize(){
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);
        A = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerA);
        B = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerB);
        C = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerC);
        D = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerD);
        next_test = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next_Text);
        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare them inside `OnCreate` method

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);
TextView A = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerA);
TextView B = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerB);
TextView C = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerC);
TextView D = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerD);
Button next_test = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next_Text);
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
.....
}
```

You should always initialize them inside `onCreate` method and put after

```
 setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);
```

Comment: That's what OP has already tried and he's unsatisfied with the result.

Comment: No, it's not. See answers by vasilis or NJ Nilesh J